# Distorted threads and bolt preload

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fasteners

Say a bolt is clamping 2 plates together, by threading into a distorted thread in the bottom plate. After the thread is used several times and becomes less distorted, will the relationship between installation torque of the screw and the clamping force between the 2 plates change significantly?

Comment: I use "eggnuts" on lots of things, but how do you cut "eggthreads" in a plate? https://www.fastenermart.com/prevailing-torque-lock-nuts.html

Answer (score 0):

If the torque is being applied to overcome distorted threads and the torque value is constant ie to a set vlaue, then the clamping force will be reduced.

If the threads are "normal" with little friction then the most of the torque applied to the set value will be applied to the clamping of the plates.